# Set Button background color MOMENTARILY - android

Tags: android, setbackground

I'm kind of new to android and have been using this code to change the background color of a `Button` when CLICKED:

```
but3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

But it stays that way and does not go back to its original color after clicking. I'd like it to change back. Please help. Here's more of the code.

`but3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Button answerButton = ((Button) v);
            String answer = answerButton.getText().toString();
            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answerButton.getText()))
            {
            score++;
            Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);
            but3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            but3.invalidate();
            }
            if(qid<20){
            currentQ=quesList1.get(qid);
            setQuestionView();
            }
            else{

            Intent intent = new Intent(ScratchActivity1.this, ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", score); 
                intent.putExtras(b); 
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_in, R.anim.activity_out);
                finish();
            }`

Comment: It depends at which case you want to change it back. Post more details.

Comment: More details above. I want to the button with the right answer(it's a quiz app) to change to a particular color momentarily to notify the user. Same goes for the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the background when the button is pressed or focused check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground) to see how you can create custom backgrounds per state (state being when a button is pressed, focused, selected etc).

If you just want to change the background after some time has passed see into using a handler:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //This will run after 1000 (defined below) milliseconds has passed
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: The handler was useful in trying to solve the problem. I used the following code to change button background: `but3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);` And then in the run() method of the handler set the background to the original color of the button: eg. `but3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);` The problem I got was that the original button background had to be set to Black for it to work properly. Other colors gave strange results, maybe someone has an answer to this issue.